# What does adding spaces inside double curly braces change?

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, does adding spaces around the expression inside the double curly braces like this `{{ expression }}` rather than this `{{expression}}` change anything?

I'm currently going through [this tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/) and [this test](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/2d7b6547bd8667b3728997a9aca87434070569ee/test/e2e/scenarios.js) doesn't pass when putting spaces, but by removing them, it passes.

Comment: Here is a plunk - no difference http://plnkr.co/edit/g2H08r

Comment: I know in the DOM output it doesn't change anything, but do you think it could change anything behind the scenes? It may just be a bug in the testing framework.

Comment: @SunilD. I copied and pasted the code exactly like on the tutorial. I'm adding the spaces on line 31 of [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/2d7b6547bd8667b3728997a9aca87434070569ee/app/index.html) file. I'm on [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04) step of the tutorial.

Comment: @mzee99 print out the return value of the `getNames()` function in that test, it is likely returning a string w/extra spaces in it, and the tests fail b/c they are expecting the phone names to match. Maybe it will help shed some light on the answer.

Comment: I don't know so much about angular cycle behind the scenes but I guess angular guys are traversing the Dom for two-way binding using regExp and remove extra space before binding occurs. So it doesn't matter you have put space before and after i suppose.

Comment: @SunilD. In both cases, `getNames()` prints out an empty object. With spaces, the test fails with this error: `Expected [  ] to equal [ 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi', 'MOTOROLA XOOM™' ].`.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no difference apart from semantics, its the same as

```
['hello', 'world']
['hello','world']
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, I guess it could be a bug in the testing framework

Answer (score 1):

`{{}}` is just a shortcut for the `ng-bind` directive which sets up a one way binding between the controller and the view, spaces or not does not matter

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if you have spaces in ng-bind view. (ng-bind view is the {{ }})